# Slightly change the bounty system; award bounty to comment if there's no answers

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, bounties

If there's a post that has no answers (and has a bounty offered), but has *helpful* comments, could the bounty be awarded to the author of the highest voted comment, *or* allow the OP to award the bounty to *one* of the authors of a comment that the OP thought was most helpful?

Comment: If a comment contains an answer people are using comments wrong

Comment: Just today I've had a situation where I opened a bounty on another user's question where the only answer was "it's impossible". A few days after the bounty was opened, a commenter agreed "it's impossible, but here is a workaround". It wasn't a full-fledged answer because it didn't answer the question but it did provide a solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps the OP can just ask the commenter to make that into an answer, then award the bounty to that answer.  Comments are *temporary*, and it doesn't seem practical to indicate that a certain comment has received a bounty award since it's not even possible.  Plus, rep isn't incurred on comments at all.  If that commenter isn't around to fulfill this request, someone else may end up making that into an answer to receive the award.  Bounties can't be awarded to self-answers, but the OP can still provide an answer based on a helpful comment as it will help others.